# Geometry of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.  How can I describe the geometry of vectors of the form
$$
  \left( \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}}, \frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}}, \frac{x_3}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}} \right) \, ?
$$
Thank you all!

Comment: This is not a subspace.  Notice that $( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} )$ is a vector in this set (set $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 1$), but $( 1,1,1 )$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$, the Cartesian product of the real line and the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

In geometric terms, the map is to project $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ along a line from $0$, onto the unit cylinder with axis the $x_1$ coordinate axis (equation $x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1$).  This cylinder is the $R \times S^1$ indicated in the first answer.

Comment: All three denominators are the same.

Comment: ok.  I reposted an answer as it is somewhat simpler than the other explanations might suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on user1551's answer a bit, notice that this locus you describe is a fibration of unit circles in the $yz$-plane over the $x$-axis. More precisely, you are interseted in the image of the map $$(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto \left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}},\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}},\frac{x_3}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}}\right),$$

which we will denote by $X$. Now consider the map $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto x$. Clearly the map $f$ is surjective and the fiber over a point $r\in \mathbb{R}$ (meaning $f^{-1}(r)$) is a circle in the $yz$-plane.